# RoR switching response formats

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Is this possible? I have an action triggered off as JS, which i respond to appropriately, but sometimes, the request fails at which point I'd like to change to respond_to format to html so that I can redirect to a thank you page. So far I've tried:

```
redirect_to(thank_you_path, format: 'html') and return if @next_question.nil?
```

but this still tries to redirect it as a js response, which of course fails......is there anyway I can convert a JS request to an HTML response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That wouldn't work because it would try to evaluate the html. You would need to return js to redirect the page